# behavior of windows while restarting of service

Tags: windows

The question is while **restarting the windows service whether windows kills the service or it waits for the process to finish**. As i remember in linux the "restart" command will kill all the child process.

Thanks in advance. I searched the question in this forum but didn't find.

Comment: Yes, it waits. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This kind of question really belongs on http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com. They are sister sites to Stack Overflow and are about general computer nerdery, whereas SO is specifically about programming. Sorry to be "that guy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting a service is just shorthand for 'stop service and start service.' So, the service gets a chance to shut down normally and then it gets a chance to start up normally.

You can see this by restarting a service in the Services MMC snap-in. I tried this on Windows 7 and the sequence UI went like this:

Windows is attempting to stop the following service on Local Computer

followed by
Windows is attempting to start the following service on Local Computer